# Bessel functions summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

I want to compute the square modulus of the following sum :

\begin{align}
\sum_p e^{i\eta p}(-\lambda)^{j-p} J_{j-p}(x)
\end{align}

Where p is an integer, j is an integer, eta is a real constant, lambda is a complex number of modulus 1, and $J_{j-p}(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order (j-p).

I know from [here](https://journals-aps-org.ezproxy.universite-paris-saclay.fr/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.34.3625) that this should be equal to :

\begin{align}
\vert \sum_p e^{i\eta p}(-\lambda)^{j-p} J_{j-p}(x) \vert^2 = J^2_{j}(x)
\end{align}

To prove this, I start as following :

\begin{align}
\vert \sum_p e^{i\eta p}(-\lambda)^{j-p} J_{j-p}(x) \vert^2 = \vert \left(\sum_p e^{i\eta p}(-\lambda)^{j-p} J_{j-p}(x) \right)^2\vert = \vert \sum_p\sum_q e^{i\eta p+q}(-\lambda)^{2j-p+q} J_{j-p}(x)  J_{j-q}(x)\vert
\end{align}

But I am stuck : which Bessel function properties I should use to arrive at the result found in the aforementioned paper? At some point I imagine orthogonality of Bessel functions is involved, but I am not sure where to start.

Does someone has a way to prove this?